# Can Resharper add a semicolon to my javascript function declaration?

Tags: javascript, resharper, automatic-semicolon-insertion

Using Visual Studio 2012, Resharper 7.0.1

If I'm editing JavaScript, and I type the following (| = cursor position):

```
this.myFunction = function() {|
```

.. Resharper will add the closing brace for me:

```
this.myFunction = function() {|}
```

... but I want it to also add a semicolon afterwards:

```
this.myFunction = function() {|};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - no, it cannot, at least in current versions. Similar feature exists for C# and VB and it is called `Complete Statement` (Ctrl-Shift-Enter), but few people use it, so adding it for JavaScript is low priority.

Comment: This is a real shame thou. I only learned of `Complete Statement` a few days ago when watching one of JetBrains ReSharper screencasts, and was eager to try it out. Was sad that it didn't work as expected for JavaScript, which is where I do most of my coding these AJAX-days... Will try to find a relevant feature request and vote.

Comment: In case someone wanted to vote the feature request/issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-339369

Comment: I can't see how "few people use it" could be accurate, seems like this is something more people could use.